# Помогите оптимизировать запрос в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос `$query=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM lvl_base WHERE steam LIKE '$rank'");` который в последующем обрабатывается. 5 таких запросов на одной странице в таблици размером от 7тыс. до 15тыс. записей, грузят пустую страницу 8-15 секунд.
Как оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: Что находится в $rank ? Есть ли индекс по полю steam и почему запросов 5, а не один

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Используйте [индексы](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%B2+mysql).
2. В вашем случае `steam LIKE = '$rank'` эквивалентно выражению `steam = '$rank'`. Оператор `=` сравнивает строку целиком, а оператор `LIKE` побуквенно каждый символ, поэтому в целом советую в данном случае использовать оператор `=`.
3. Судя по всему 5 раз у вас запрос выполняется просто с различными значениями `$rank`, поэтому лучше в данном случае выполнить 1 запрос вместо 5 используя оператор `IN`, например: `WHERE steam IN ('$rank1', '$rank2', '$rank3', ...)` либо используя оператор `OR`, например: `WHERE (steam = '$rank1') OR (steam = '$rank2') OR (steam = '$rank3') OR ...`
4. Не используйте для выборки `SELECT * FROM ...`, возможно у вас в БД лежат большие данные в каждой строке. Используйте для выборки только нужные поля, например `SELECT id, name ... FROM ...`
5. Используйте `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` - ограничивайте выборку, делайте её постраничной
6. Размер таблицы в вашем случае не слишком велик, 7-15 тысяч это субьективно мало, скорее всего тормоза возникают где-то в другом месте.

Проверяйте свой код :)

Comment: 2) Почему Вы решили, что в `$rank` отсутствуют подстановочные символы? Нет, оно, скорее всего, именно так, но в общем случае этот пункт выглядит странно.

Comment: @Akina в данном конкретном случае, скорее всего без символов `%`, но да, в случае если они есть, то только `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

- Создайте индекс для столбца `steam`
- Делайте не 5 запросов, а 1
- Используйте `limit`
- Выбирайте не все столбцы, а только нужные: `select (column1, column2)`,

P.S. Экранируйте спецсимволы в переменной `$rank`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но прироста не дало (веря Гугл) $rank - STEAM_ID:0:1:737283949562. 5 запросов для каждой базы. Разная статистика игрока

Comment: @СашаСтоколос надо разбираться. возможно дело не в запросе

Comment: ошибка была в js. Спасибо за советы, но видимо тут оптимизировать уже некуда. 7-15тыс в каждой базе - это видимо мало